# What is the role of the `return` statement?

Tags: function, methods, syntax, return

I'm struggling to grasp the importance of the `return` statement.

Can someone in layman terms explain it to me? Especially the power behind it.

I have read definitions, seen examples, and understand how it works. But I also read that it extremely powerful and important, and that it is only used in functions (or methods if within a class).

Can anyone offer an in-depth explanation?

Comment: Functions allow you to perform computations and execute algorithms. Sometimes, you want to know what the result of an algorithm was. Thus, inside your function, you `return` the result and then outside code has access to it.

Comment: `return` a calculated value... There. Layman terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything is an object in python, even functions. A function can be assigned to a variable, passed to another function and can be returned from another function.

`return` statment helps a  function to return a value to the calling statement. The reason why it is powerful is because variables in python can be used to return functions from other functions.

This allows it to perform some interesting things like decoupling functions using `decorators`.

To know about **Decorators** read [this](http://blog.apcelent.com/python-decorator-tutorial-with-example.html)

Comment: It don't think the question was asking about returning function objects

Comment: Thanks- I'm new to python. Lots of this is above my head- thus trying to seek a more "dumbed" down description- like your second paragraph.